# Configure Emacs to use Chrome as the web browser of choice?

Tags: configuration, emacs

Using [Emacs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) on a Linux system I click:

```
Scala>Browser Scala API
```

which produces a terminal window with this message:

```
/usr/bin/xterm: Can't execvp lynx: No such file or directory
```

How do I inform Emacs that the correct web browser to use is Chrome?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506249/how-to-make-emacs-org-mode-open-links-to-sites-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 1):

Based on a [meta discussion](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1396/how-do-we-feel-about-copying-answers-from-other-se-sites), I'm copying [Trey Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4506458/4957508)'s accepted answer as well as [Alan Turing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6309985/4957508)'s "google-chrome"-specific answer here:

---

**Trey Jackson's answer**

Emacs 23.2 doesn't directly support chrome, but it does support a "generic" browser, and something like this should work:

```
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic
      browse-url-generic-program "chromium-browser")
```

You don't mention your OS, but if it's Windows or Mac, you can try:

```
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-default-windows-browser)
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-default-macosx-browser)
```

And, if that doesn't work, there are other folks who have implemented `'browse-url-chrome`.  Google turned up the following links:

- http://code.ohloh.net/search?s=browse-url-chrome&browser=Default

---

**Alan Turing's answer**

As @Trey suggests, you can set it to a generic browser bu instead of "chromium-browser" use "google-chrome", like this:

```
(setq browse-url-browser-function 'browse-url-generic
      browse-url-generic-program "google-chrome")
```

That worked for me with Emacs 23.2 and Chrome 12. Though it might be Chrome 13 by the time I'm done writing this answer ;-)